# How to deploy a React App with SSR on cPanel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

so here is the thing, I have created a react app with server side rendering (with babel and webpack and an express server). I was able to run it locally. So far So good.
Now I want to publish it on the web, and I am clueless about how to do that, there isn't much documentation about that and I wasn't able to get an answer so far.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you want is a service that can host and run your NodeJS code. I may be wrong but I dont think cPanel does that- it is used to manage static resources of a static website - not a ssr one. You can try platforms like Heroku that allow you to deploy node apps out of the box OR use something like Google Cloud or AWS to set up your own VM and run the NodeJS application there. Some of the latter services also provide out of the box environments for running apps like apps engine (GCP) or elastic beanstalk (AWS)

Answer (score 0):

If It's an hobby project you can do that with Heroku. It's free. Else you can buy a Heroku premium or Digital ocean or AWS EC2 server

Comment: I would suggest upload your front end to vercel or netlify and upload you backend to aws or heroku or digital ocean. But how do you make a SSR app with plane react and express? I thought it was only possible with next.js.

Comment: Well it is not a hobby project, and what if I want to go with other hosting options? Aren't there any ways to do so on a cPanel? I have seen some tutorials about deploying NodeJs apps on cPanel, but not for the case I am looking for, I am not sure if it applies

Comment: check this out this out https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/typescript-nodejs-react-ssr. There are many other tutorials. However it is not so easy to get started with. Maybe Next.js is the easier way to go I am not sure